# Highcharts: How to toggle between different xaxis having individual plotbands, onclick rangeselector buttons

Tags: plot, highcharts, range, selector, axis

I have a chart with daily values of the month of October. 
Two buttons: week and month.
Week plotband has to be identical with month plotband: First 2 days are green, next 5 days are blue in month plotband. When selecting week, the range date 1-7 should be same colour green and blue.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
    },

    title: {
        text: 'How long time a TR has been placed in stages longer than 48 hours'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Input - verify should max be 48 hours = green zone'
    },

    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {

        },
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{point.y}'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {

    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttonSpacing: 10,
        enabled: true,
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 1,
        buttons: [{
            type: 'week',
            count: 1,
            text: 'Week'
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: 'Month'
        }],
    },
    xAxis: [{
        id: 'one',
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H:%M',
            day: '%e. %b',
            week: '%e. %b',
            month: '%b \'%y',
            year: '%Y'
        },

        plotBands: [{
            from: 1538352000000,
            to: 1538524800000,
            color: '#E8F5E9'

        }, {
            from: 1538524800000,
            to: 1538870400000,
            color: '#E0ECEC'
        }, {
            from: 1538870400000,
            to: 1539475200000,
            color: "#FFFDE7"
        }, {
            from: 1539475200000,
            to: 1540944000000,
            color: "#FFEBEE"
        }],
    }, {
        id: 'two',
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H:%M',
            day: '%e. %b',
            week: '%e. %b',
            month: '%b \'%y',
            year: '%Y'
        },

        plotBands: [{
            from: 1538352000000,
            to: 1538524800000,
            color: '#E8F5E9'

        }, {
            from: 1538524800000,
            to: 1538870400000,
            color: '#E0ECEC'
        }],
    }],

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: 'TRADING RECORDS',
        }
    }
});
```

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marialaustsen/v4hdLe3g/)

Is there a way to toggle between two xaxis with different plotBands: when clicking on the 'week' button, one plotband will display and when clicking on the 'month' button another plotband will display. So the colours of the plotband is relative to the dates? 
I assume I have to use event functions like setExtremes and afterSetExtremes, but not sure how to do it?
Thanks much appreciated for help.

I managed to simulate the output with this function:

```
  events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
        if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton" &&
            e.rangeSelectorButton.text == "Week") {
            // it is your button that caused this,
            // so setExtrememes to your custom
            // have to do in timeout to let
            // highcharts finish processing events...
            setTimeout(function () {
                Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(1538352000000, 1538524800000)
            }, 1);

        }


    },
}
```

But it only work when selecting specific: setExtremes(1538352000000, 1538524800000)
I think a scaleable solution for any 7 days would require some sort of exception functionality for remove current plotband on xaxis with addplotband

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marialaustsen/v4hdLe3g/)

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you're trying to achieve? Because toggling between two xaxis is not a good idea. Perhaps you should add your custom buttons and use `setExtremes` to set a specific range or use `navigator`.

Answer (score 0):

I added custom buttons instead:  https://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?t=31649

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
         <button class="btn btn-custom" id="one">48 hours</button>
         <button class="btn btn-custom" id="two">7 days</button>
         <button class="btn btn-custom" id="three">14 days</button>
         <button class="btn btn-custom" id="four">31 days</button>
         <button class="btn btn-custom" id="all">All</button>
   </div>

    <div id="containerbenchmark"></div>

$.get('bm.csv', function (bmcsv) {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'containerbenchmark',
            type: 'areaspline',
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Input - verify - close should max be 48 hours = green zone'
        },

        data: {
            csv: bmcsv,
        },

        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    format: '{point.y}'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            /*headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 16px">{point.key}</span><br/>',    
            pointFormat: '<span style="font-size: 14px; color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <span style="font-size: 14px">{point.y} {point.total}</span><br/>',
            footerFormat:  '<span style="font-size: 16px">{point.total}</span><br/>',*/
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var tooltip = '<table><span style="font-size: 16px">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e/%b/%Y',
                    new Date(this.x)) + '</span><br/><tbody>';
                //loop each point in this.points
                $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
                    tooltip += '<tr><th style="font-size: 14px; color: ' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + ': </th>' +
                        '<td style="font-size: 14px; text-align: right">' + point.y + '</td></tr>'
                });
                tooltip += '<tr><th style="font-size: 16px">Total: </th>' +
                    '<td style="font-size: 16px; text-align:right"><span>' + this.points[0].total + '</span></td></tr>' +
                    '</tbody></table>';
                return tooltip;
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 2,
            enabled: true,
            inputEnabled: true,
            inputDateFormat: "%m/%d/%Y",
            inputEditDateFormat: "%m/%d/%Y",
            inputDateParser: function (s) {
                return Date.UTC(
                    parseInt(s.substr(6, 4)),
                    parseInt(s.substr(0, 2) - 1),
                    parseInt(s.substr(3, 2)),
                    12
                )
            }
        },

        navigator: {
            enabled: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour: '%H:%M',
                day: '%e. %b',
                week: '%e. %b',
                month: '%b \'%y',
                year: '%Y'
            },

            plotBands: [{
                from: 1538352000000,
                to: 1538524800000,
                color: '#cae8cc',
                label: {
                    text: '> 48 hours',
                    style: {
                        color: 'black',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        textTransform: 'uppercase',
                        fontSize: '14px'
                    }
                }
            }, {
                from: 1538524800000,
                to: 1538870400000,
                color: '#d0e2e2',
                label: {
                    text: '> 7 days',
                    style: {
                        color: 'black',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        textTransform: 'uppercase',
                        fontSize: '14px'
                    }
                }
            }, {
                from: 1538870400000,
                to: 1539475200000,
                color: "#fff9b3",
                label: {
                    text: '> 14 days',
                    style: {
                        color: 'black',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        textTransform: 'uppercase',
                        fontSize: '14px'
                    }
                }
            }, {
                from: 1539475200000,
                to: 1540944000000,
                color: "#ffb3be",
                label: {
                    text: '> 31 days',
                    style: {
                        color: 'black',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        textTransform: 'uppercase',
                        fontSize: '14px'
                    }
                }
            }],


        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'TRADING RECORDS',
            }
        }
    }, function (chart) {

        // apply the date pickers
        setTimeout(function () {
            var rangeSelector = $('#containerbenchmark input.highcharts-range-selector');

            rangeSelector.datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true
            }) /*.datepicker('update', new Date())*/ ;

            var inputMin = rangeSelector.filter('[name=min]');
            var inputMax = rangeSelector.filter('[name=max]');

            inputMin.datepicker().on("changeDate", function (event) {
                console.log(inputMin.datepicker("getDate"));
                console.log(inputMin.datepicker("getUTCDate"));
            });
        }, 1000);
    });

    $('#one').click(function () {
        toggleActiveState(false);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
            1538352000000,
            1538524800000
        );
    });
    $('#two').click(function () {
        toggleActiveState(false);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
            1538524800000,
            1538870400000
        );
    });
    $('#three').click(function () {
        toggleActiveState(false);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
            1538870400000,
            1539475200000
        );
    });
    $('#four').click(function () {
        toggleActiveState(false);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
            1539475200000,
            1540944000000
        );
    });
    $('#all').click(function () {
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
            event.min,
            event.max
        );
    });
});
```